# ASP.NET VB, when button is press, how can I have it go to another form instad of always returing to the same form?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to have a website with string 4 forms together.  Right now I cannot figure out how to get asp to go to another page, always returns to the same page.

I would like it so when the enter button is press the asp vb code would check to make sure the data is valid.  If it is not valid it would return to the same form. else, go to the next form

Right now I have a test project that has a text box and a button.  If you type yes I would like it to go to another form, else stay on same form

This is the vb code I have

```
Partial Class firstform
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '' proccess the form check for errors

        If (nextpage.Text = "yes") Then
            '' go to next form
        End If

        '' return tp pre form secondform.aspx
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you need the postback data, you could also do a cross-page postback by setting the button's PostbackUrl property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply [`Reponse.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to your next page.

```
If nextpage.Text = "yes"
   Page.Validate()
   If Page.IsValid Then
       Response.Redirect("OtherForm.aspx")
    End If
End If
```

Or you could use the [Wizard Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx)

[MSDN: Wizard Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a wizard control for this kind of interface?

If you really need to go to another page, you can use the PostbackUrl property of the button.

You can also use validation controls and check the Page.IsValid property before you redriect.